# Does "the other side of the receipt" sound natural in American English

Tags: word-choice, american-english

> Kindly, look at the other side of the receipt. You will find a link
>   through which you can rate our service.

The aim of this sentence is to make a customer pay attention to the link because it is written on the other side of the receipt. Is the sentence correct, polite, and expressing the required meaning?

Is the expression "The other side" accurate? I mean what do you call the golden side of the shown picture? Is it called back, back-side, flip the paper, or something else?

[image]

Comment: It's understandable, although this US English speaker would probably say "the **back** of the receipt."

Comment: Please wait for at least 12–24 hours before accepting an answer. Usually that way you get more answers because people see your question as not having an accepted answer yet, which in turn means you can choose which one answers your question best. I'm not saying the current one is wrong, but that you'd get more out of your question. : )

Comment: @userr2684291 - When leaving a comment like that, feel free to link to the [Not So Fast meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer), too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly understandable, though I would suggest that it could be made more direct and effective by giving the user a reason to turn over before asking them to.

As currently drafted, you're asking the user to turn over the receipt. They might do that, then wonder why they did if they hadn't read the next sentence.

I would suggest rephrasing the sentence as:

> To find a link through which you can rate our service, please turn over this receipt.

Alternatively, if you do want to refer to the back of the receipt and to be as direct as possible, respecting the user's time:

> To rate our service, please use the link on the back of this receipt.

If you're attempting to get as many users (customers?) as possible to turn over the receipt, I would recommend trying multiple different messages with different links in a multivariate test.

Comment: A "multi-variant A:B test"? Are you by any chance conflating A/B tests with multivariate ones?

Comment: Valid point. I originally wrote A:B but reconsidered since I had suggested using multiple messages and unfortunately ended up with both. I'll edit.

Comment: Did you mean to say ***multivariate test*** perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can refer to the *other side* for something which is flat, like a receipt or other piece of paper, which has only one other side, or where there is only one other side of interest.

It is almost never the case, however, that information about the transaction is printed on both sides. It is almost always printed on only one side, and the back is left blank or used for marketing messages, policy statements, coupons, and indeed, in this case the URL for a customer survey. It would be far more customary to refer to the *front* and *back* of the receipt.

More importantly (in my opinion), *[kindly](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51618/)* is not much if ever used by native speakers of American English to make requests except in very formal circumstances. *Please* would be used almost exclusively for customer relations.

> Please see the back of this receipt for a link to rate our service.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using *other* is that it is too general and not specific. Suppose I said:

> Look at the other side of the receipt

Which side am I referring to? If you happened to be looking at the front, that  would mean the back; if you are looking at the back, that comment would refer to the front.

Now, in your context, the word *other* would work, because the message is printed on one side of the receipt. But I still think it sounds a little clumsy. It's not rude, and it's not incorrect, but I think that this sounds much more polished and professional:

> Look at the back of the receipt

There's one other advantage, too: you can use that same wording on a sign near the exit of your business, where the expression *other side* would not work as well:

> Kindly look at the back of your receipt to find a link through which you can rate our service.

As a footnote, notice how I removed the comma after *kindly*. We're not supposed to proofread here, but that comma really shouldn't be there.

Comment: The key is that the message is printed on the receipt itself, so which side is the *other* one is obvious—the side other than the one where the message is printed. Similarly, a shop may have four walls but only two entrances, so *other* is clear from context; if there are multiple other entrances, then yes, you would need to be more specific or refer to *another/a different/one of the other/etc.* entrance. Otherwise, I agree that referring to the *back* is more idiomatic.