# How to ask for Reimbursement?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

How can we ask for - "To make repayment for expense or loss incurred"?

I have to write a mail to online e-Commerce site as on their site they have mentioned wrong detail/amount for product and I have made extra payment.

**So is this sentence correct?**

> Please do the needful and reimburse.

Comment: I've paid more for the product. Kindly check, and *refund* - this may work.

Answer (score 1):

**reimburse** needs an object, like this:

```
Please reimburse me for the difference in price
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this :

> *The amount you mentioned for the product is wrong, and because of which I did an extra payment. So, in that case you need to refund me the extra amount that I paid for the product.*

Comment: *'I made an extra payment...'* '...did an extra payment'* is typical Indian! :)

Comment: @MaulikV, I'm an Indian and I'm proud of it as well. I guess its way of writing. you liked that way so you wrote it and I wrote that. India is not all included in this topic.

Comment: @MaulikV , This is not the place to make fun of any country... This community is to learn English.. Not to point out any country name.... You are also an Indian

Comment: @Pallavi I'm an Indian and *thus* I know this! However, you missed my point. I said it's an Indian way to write OR It's Indian English. I have been asking many such questions on InE. For instance, if you use '[Kindly do the needful](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17278/whats-a-preferred-alternative-to-the-phrase-do-the-needful)', others will surely say - it's typical Indian!

Comment: Nehal, many Indians *like* writing/speaking English in their own way. But 'liking' is different than what is 'correct'!

Comment: @Ms.Nehal Indian English has nothing to do with the country, India. It is a writing style like British and American English. All are proud of their respective countries. The only aim of this platform is to learn the correct way of writing English.

Comment: @MaulikV, yes I know liking is different from Correct, but I don't think so that using `did` in place of `made` really made that huge difference and which led to a wrong answer. And you cannot say that the answer I gave is completely incorrect

Comment: Where do you find 'completely' in my comments? Note that I *did not* downvote your answer too. I just said that there are dozens of things in English we Indians think are right...but they are *not!*. Take it, or trash it! It all depends whether or not you want to learn.