# I want to make friendship with you

Tags: idioms, semantics

I know that **to make friends with somebody** is idiomatic in English.

But in India I hear people saying

> I want to make friendship with you

I think native speakers do not accept *make friendship with somebody.* I do not know whether it is grammatically correct or not.

But I think the following sentences are grammatically correct.

> 1. I want to be your friend.
> 2. I want to start friendship with you.

I want to know know other possible expressions with regard to *make friends*

I herewith attach a [link](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/make-friends) which shows the usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are aware that *something* is Indian English, be cautious using it before the English speaking community. Though some InE expressions (such as *'kindly do the needful';* *'picturization of something'*) are now at least understood if not well accepted, they still have some *grey* area to improve.

Again, you are correct!

> *I want to make friendship with you* is InE but well understood.

The other variations as you asked may include...

> *strike up a friendship*

**or simply**...

> *let's be friends (a bit informal)* 
>  *let's have frienship (again, informal)*

Comment: @Mauik V. some of the so called Indian English expressions are borrowed from old English.Do the needful is not entirely Indian English

Comment: Nope! [It **was** originated in India](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/do-the-needful/) but was spoken in England lately. Again, due to Indian influence there. Nevertheless, they stopped using it later. However, I never said that it is ungrammatical or unusual! It would just sound *foreign* today in those countries.

Comment: Useful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17278/whats-a-preferred-alternative-to-the-phrase-do-the-needful